# Getting 403 for unsafe methods | DRF React Production

Tags: django, deployment, django-rest-framework, axios, http-status-code-403

I'm getting 403 forbidden error for the unsafe methods (PUT, POST, DELETE) in the deployed Django project. I'm using react as front-end.

I'm using axios to send the request to the DRF view. I've included the below lines to send the csrf token with the header as X-CSRFToken.

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

In my local everything is working fine. I've deployed this project with NGINX and Gunicorn in a Linux server. There I'm facing an issue while sending the request with unsafe methods. I'm not sure why its not working when it is deployed in the Linux server.

Can anyone please help me on this. Please :(

Comment: Can we see your settings file and Nginx config for the main server block

Comment: @MattSeymour Thanks for your reply. I'm getting this error. "detail": "CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - https://url/api/no-access-details/?environment=data does not match any trusted origins."

Comment: Is there anything I need to configure in settings.py for this.

Comment: got it i need to add CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['url']